# hibernate tries to insert column that is not defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my case, I need to inherit token object from abstract item class. By hibernate conventions, it should be the holder of id field and every child class simply inherits it. So there should be no problem here. I tried to follow conventions and specifications as accurately as possible, and here's a slice of code with my entities:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<HolderInfo> holders = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected ItemTypeEnum itemType;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AuctionLot sellerLot;

    public ItemTypeEnum getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public boolean hasHolder(Long userId) {
        return holders.stream().anyMatch(holderInfo -> holderInfo.getHolder().getId() == userId);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Token extends Item {
    @Value("${ethereum.minterAddress}")
    private String DEFAULT_HOLDER;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "token_eth_id")
    private BigInteger tokenId;

    @Embedded
    private TokenInfo tokenInfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "token", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<>();

    public Token(BigInteger id, String uri, String addressFactory, String addressNFT, String name, String description,
            BigInteger defaultPrice, User holder) {
        this.tokenId = id;
        this.tokenInfo = new TokenInfo(uri, addressFactory, addressNFT, name, description, defaultPrice);
        this.holders = Sets.newHashSet(new HolderInfo(this, holder));
        this.itemType = ItemTypeEnum.TOKEN;
    }
    ......
}

@Embeddable
public class TokenInfo {

    @Column(length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String uri;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String addressFactory;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String addressNFT;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;
    @Column(length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 1000, nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigInteger price;

    public TokenInfo(String uri, String addressFactory, String addressNFT, Date dateCreated, String name,
            String description, BigInteger defaultPrice) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.addressFactory = addressFactory;
        this.addressNFT = addressNFT;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = defaultPrice;
    }
    ...
}
```

It looks OK for me, but once I run integration test, it fails trying to insert not existing column, which I haven't specified anywhere. The error message:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [Test worker] Column "ITEM_ID" not found; SQL statement:
insert into token (item_type, item_id, default_holder, token_eth_id, address_factory, addressnft, date_created, description, name, price, uri, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-200]
```

I tried to specify column name with @Column annotation, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: `Item` isn't abstract, if it should be make it so and use `@MappedSuperclass` instead of `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you added the column into database but you havent specefied it in the Entity. Also if you change the column name like here for example:

@Column(nullable = false, name = "token_eth_id")
private BigInteger tokenId;

It can cause problems sometimes. I remember that there was some bug in library. Please keep alias and column name same.
You can even try some older hibernate library maybe it will work.

Also, Item is not abstract as you said that it is.

I can't tell you more because I would need whole picture of this problem and debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way I could have changed anything in my database since it is a test log message, and I use @AutoConfigureTestDatabase, which under the hood uses h2 in memory database.